# Why does my Applications take up 79GB of storage but I don't see what is actually using all the storage

Tags: macos, applications, storage

[image: Screenshot of places I know where i can view my storage usage]

I tried to clear up some storage but I see 79gb of storage used by my applications but i can't see what is taking it up